# Video.js: Set current time and open timeline position

Tags: javascript, video.js

I need to have timestamps in links to videos on my site, e.g. http://example.com/videos/hdy5fdg?time=231

I've found lots of answers that explain how to do it - just use `player.currentTime(231)` and nothing more.

But the problem in this case is that the video is displayed like this:

[image]

If you click play, it starts from the given time, but the problem is users are not aware of this fact.

What I need is the player is displayed like this initially if there's a timestamp in the URL:

[image]

So it should be preloaded, the timeline is visible and it is paused.

Is it possible?

Here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-clarke-ygbqe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `vjs-has-started` class to put the controls into that state.

```
player.addClass('vjs-has-started');
```